# Using both `event-apply-meta-modifier` and `event-apply-super-modifier` for the same shortcut

Tags: key-bindings, modifier-key

I use the commands `event-apply-meta-modifier` and `event-apply-super-modifier` to have keys I can tap that apply the meta and super modifier to the next typed shortcut. But when I first apply the meta modifier, then tap the key that should apply the super modifier, Emacs doesn't stack the modifiers but instead says

```
M-` is undefined
```

(I have `event-apply-super-modifier` on the `-key). So I tried to define a command

```
(defun ahp/event-apply-meta-and-super-modifier ()
  "This function kills all lines in the buffer of a regexp-search using the all-package."
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'event-apply-meta-modifier)
  (call-interactively 'event-apply-super-modifier)
  )
```

But when I use this command Emacs says

```
ahp/event-apply-meta-and-super-modifier: Wrong type argument: commandp, event-apply-meta-modifier
```

How can I make this command work?

Comment: but `event-apply-meta-modifier` is not a command

Comment: @shynur is correct of course (that's why you get the error message), but there are other, deeper problems here. For one, each of these functions does a `(read-event)`, so you have two different events, one in each call - what you want to do is modify the *same* event twice: I don't think that's possible with these functions: you'll have to go to a lower-level function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simply concatenated the definitions of those two functions:

```lisp
(defun MetaSuper-next-cmd ()
  (interactive)
  (execute-kbd-macro (vector (event-apply-modifier (event-apply-modifier (read-event) 'super 23 "s-") 'meta 27 "M-"))))
```

Test:

```lisp
(keymap-global-set "M-s-<left>" #'beginning-of-defun)
(keymap-global-set "M-s-j" #'beginning-of-defun)
```

`M-x MetaSuper-next-cmd <left>` or `M-x MetaSuper-next-cmd j`.